# How to read a spreadsheet vertically

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working in Google Scripts in combination with Google spreadsheets. The idea is that I make a spreadsheet that is able to read out events in a calendar. I am able to read to through the sheet horizontally, however I want to be able to read through it vertically.

See the script I have so far below.

```
function caltest1() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 23;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 10);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();

    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var tstart = new Date(row[1]);
        var tstop = new Date(row[7]);
        var title = row[0];  // First column
        var desc = row[2];       // Second column
        var guest = row[8];
        var loc = row[9];
        cal.createEvent(title, tstart, { description: desc, location: loc, sendInvites: true, guests: guest });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain about the relationship between the script, the image and ``horizontally``, ``vertically``?

Comment: the script can only read through the sheet horizontally, meaning that for every row I have to make a copy of the script. so instead of reading through the sheet horizontally I want the script to go vertically, as this would be more efficient. does that clarify it for you?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about your situation. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: You can use [tag:google-sheets-api]  to get data vertically using `majorDimension: 'COLUMNS'`. Alternatively, you can transpose the data array using `Array.map()`